# Change database dynamically in SQL Server using a stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server: how to change database name dynamically and use one select and insert statment to load data using a stored procedure.

How to change the database name with insert and select statement while table data loading into another table?

Here each database name related table load into with in the database name related target table.

i.e  database: test and source table: emp    target table is :emptarget  here emp  table records load into emptarget  similar to another databases

Database names information maintain one table.

```
USE [test]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[databaseinformation]
(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [databasename] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[databaseinformation] ([id], [databasename]) 
VALUES (1, N'test'), (2, N'test1')
GO
```

Table1 : source : emp and datbasename: test

```
USE [test]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp]
(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [sal] [int] NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [sal]) 
VALUES (19, N'hd', 40), (1, N'g', 10),
       (9, N'dk', 90), (80, N'dhe', 80)
GO
```

Target table : emptarget and databasename: test

```
USE [test]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emptarget]
(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [sal] [int] NULL
) 

----table 2: emp and databasename: test1
USE [test]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp]
(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [sal] [int] NULL
) 

INSERT [dbo].[emp] ([id], [name], [sal]) 
VALUES (50, N'kl', 80), 39, N'abc', 10)
go
```

Target table : emptarget and databasename: test1

```
USE [test1]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emptarget]
(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [sal] [int] NULL
)
```

Finally need to load data like below

Database: test  and table : emptarget

```
id  |name   |sal
19  |hd |40
1   |g  |10
9   |dk |90
80  |dhe    |80
```

Database: test1  and table : emptarget

```
id  |name   |sal
50  |kl |80
39  |abc    |10
```

I tried like below

```
USE [test]
GO

insert into emptarget 
select * from emp 

USE [test1]
GO
insert into emptarget 
select * from emp
```

Here I do not want run two queries separately. I need to run querying using single select and insert statement to load data correspong tables with databases.

Please tell me how to write query to achive this task in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have no idea about why you don't do this.

```sql
insert into test.emptarget select * from test.emp; 
insert into test1.emptarget select * from test1.emp;
```

So I think you just want one query to do this.

```sql
create procedure emptoemptarget (@DBName nvarchar(10))
as
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(1000)

    set @sql = 'insert into ' + @DBName + '.emptarget select * from ' + @DBName + '.emp'

    exec (@sql)
end


select dbo.emptoemptarget(name) from sys.databases where name in ('test','test1')
```